# Working with piecewise answer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Sometimes MatLab gives me answer in `piecewise` notation, like this:

> piecewise([1 < x, 0], [abs(x) < 1, -(log(x - 1) - 1)*(x - 1)])

Is it possible to take any pair from answer?

For example, take second pair from previous answer (will be `-(log(x - 1) - 1)*(x - 1)`).

P.S. I using Symbolic Toolbox in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From the online [MATLAB R2014b documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html) :

> **Access Methods**
>
> ...
>
> **expression** — Object in a specific branch
>
> expression(p, i)
>
> Instead of piecewise::expression(p, i), the index operator p[i] can be
>   used synonymously.

In your example, `p` would be your original answer, and `i` would be 2.
You can also access the condition of a branch using `condition(p, i)`, the whole branch by `branch(p, i)`, or the number of branches by `numberOfBranches(p)`.